# regex the text string in python and split into arrays

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a text like:

```
//string
s = CS -135IntrotoComputingCS -154IntroToWonderLand...
```

in array like

```
inputarray[0]= CS -135 Intro to computing
inputarray[1]= CS -154 Intro to WonderLand
.
.
```

.
and so on;
I am trying something like this:

```
re.compile("[CS]+\s").split(s)
```

But it's just not ready to even break, even if I try something like

re.compile("[CS]").split(s)

If anyone can throw some light on this?

Comment: How are you going to convert `135IntrotoComputingCS` to `-135 Intro to computing`? (Unless they are all in "intro to x" format which I don't think it is) Where are you getting this data? Maybe you can get it in a better format.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `findall` with a lookahead regex as this:

```
>>> s = 'CS -135IntrotoComputingCS -154IntroToWonderLand'
>>> print re.findall(r'.+?(?=CS|$)', s)
```

```
['CS -135IntrotoComputing', 'CS -154IntroToWonderLand']
```

Regex: `.+?(?=CS|$)` matches 1+ any characters that has `CS` at next position or end of line.

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava, it worked! the only thing is that it breaks when i have CS -135IntrotoCS,  then in that case it again mark CS as a different member of the array!

Comment: Can you please update your question and show me input string with expected output.

Comment: May . be you can use: `re.findall(r'.+?(?=CS -|$)', s)`

Answer (score 0):

Although `findall` is more straightforward but `finditer` can also be used here

```
s = 'CS -135IntrotoComputingCS -154IntroToWonderLand'
x=[i.start() for i in re.finditer('CS ',s)] # to get the starting positions of 'CS'
count=0
l=[]
while count+1<len(x):
    l.append(s[x[count]:x[count+1]])
    count+=1
l.append(s[x[count]:])
print(l) # ['CS -135IntrotoComputing', 'CS -154IntroToWonderLand']
```